# New line in help insight

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe7

With tooltip help insight I can display some extra comments when hovering over a classname/fieldname/procedurename etc. like this:

```
/// <comments>Some comments on e.g. a class.</comments>
```

How can I force a new line in the text shown?

Comment: Try `/// <comments>This is the first line.<br>This should be the next line.</comments>`. They say in [this manual](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/Delphi-Documentation-Guidelines.pdf) that *All common HTML tags such as <p>, <b>, <i>, <u>, <a>, <img>, etc. should be also supported*, but if `<br>` tag falls into that *etc.* I can't verify, as I have no Delphi by hand right now.

Comment: Thank you @TLama, unfortunately it doesn't work. The <br> tag is not recognized and the whole comment is not displayed. :-(

Comment: Does it need to be XML? So `<br/>`.

Comment: Thanks @David, but no luck either.

Comment: Guess you are out of luck then

Comment: Are you using XE or XE7. Title says XE, question says XE7.

Comment: I'm using XE7. And I too guess I'm out of luck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please can you fix the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Judging by my experiments (see twice-updated answer), you're right that it has to be XML. If it isn't, the tag and what follows it is ignored by Help Insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XE7 and XE8 the following

```
  public
    { Public declarations }
    /// <comments>Some comments<para/>comments on a second line</comments>
    procedure SetUp;
```

puts the text 'comments on a second line' on a new line in the Help Insight pop-up.  A minor quirk is the second line is indented a couple of spaces, but if I do

```
/// <comments>Some comments<para>comments on a second line</para>third line</comments>
```

the 'third line' isn't indented. The indentation inconsistency can by masked (at the expense of indenting everything by two spaces) by doing:

```
///<comments><para>Some comments</para><para>comments on a second line</para><para>third</para></comments>
procedure SetUp;
```

Judging by experiments, the

```
<p/>
```

XML tag used to work in XE4, but stopped working by XE7, as in my initial test:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CDS: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure CDSCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    ///<comments>Some comments<p/>more</comments>
    procedure AddHLIndex;
```

In XE4 the above displays the 'more' on a new line in XE4 but on the same line as 'Some comments' in XE8.

I wondered whether the difference in XE8 was anything to do with the presence of Castalia, but I get the same difference between XE4 and XE8 with XE8 started with the /NOCASTALIA switch.

I haven't tested exhaustively but XE8 ignores all the 'HTML' formatting tags I've tried (except the

```
<c>
```

tag mentioned by the questioner), which might be the result of a deliberate change or an accident, of course. On the other hand, it does seem to process HTML escapes such as

```
&gt;
```

and

```
&lt;
```

but not, unfortunately,

```
&#10;
```

, which it just ignores.

Comment: The IDE can also compile the in memory edit buffer rather than the disk file

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for sharing. The only formatting I found working is <c></c>.

Comment: @MartynA <para/> indeed does the trick. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Just found: <para>some text</para> gives a new line with a bit indentation.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that - see update about 'third line' in my answer.  I guess it's a flaw in the implementation.

Comment: See latest update for an imperfect way of left-aligning several lines.